# Page not showing in React.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am trying to build a landing page based on React.js but after everything I did with react.js bootstrap the page is not showing but only showing as the original default react page;

here's the App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <p>
          Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
        <a
          className="App-link"
          href="https://reactjs.org"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
          Learn React
        </a>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import { Card } from "react-bootstrap";
import { Button } from "react-bootstrap";

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
const Example = (props) => {
  return (
<Card style={{ width: "18rem" }}>
  <Card.Img variant="top" src="holder.js/100px180" />
  <Card.Body>
    <Card.Title>Card Title</Card.Title>
    <Card.Text>
      Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of
      the card's content.
    </Card.Text>
    <Button variant="primary">Go somewhere</Button>
  </Card.Body>
</Card>
  );
};

export default Example;[enter image description here][1]
serviceWorker.unregister();
```

I was wondering is there some file that i missed to import or export since i am new to React.js, please help thanks!

Answer (score 1):

so you are rendering the original App to the page: `ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));`

If you customise the App file rather than in the index, e.g.

```
function App() { = (props) => {
  return (
<Card style={{ width: "18rem" }}>
  <Card.Img variant="top" src="holder.js/100px180" />
  <Card.Body>
    <Card.Title>Card Title</Card.Title>
    <Card.Text>
      Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of
      the card's content.
    </Card.Text>
    <Button variant="primary">Go somewhere</Button>
  </Card.Body>
</Card>
  );
};

export default App;
```

It should then be rendered on the page.

Answer (score 1):

I can see from your code that your **App Component** will render to the DOM.

Are you also looking for your **Example component** ??
Then you need to first include your Example Component somewhere into APP Component itself ***(Import Example in app.js)*** and then render your App component to DOM in index.js

Answer (score 1):

hey you are rendering the app component 
here this line is doing that `ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));`

if you want to render Example component ,you need to put it inside App.js file like below

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import { Card } from "react-bootstrap";
import { Button } from "react-bootstrap";

function App() {
  return (
   <Card style={{ width: "18rem" }}>
  <Card.Img variant="top" src="holder.js/100px180" />
  <Card.Body>
    <Card.Title>Card Title</Card.Title>
    <Card.Text>
      Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of
      the card's content.
    </Card.Text>
    <Button variant="primary">Go somewhere</Button>
  </Card.Body>``
</Card>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**add export default App in bottom answer updated**

Comment: hi @warmachine thank you so answering! bu it threw back this error ```
Attempted import error: './App' does not contain a default export (imported as 'App'). ``` in index.js what does it mean?

Answer (score 0):

Desired result can be achieved like this:

App component:

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";

const App = (props) => {
  return (
<Card style={{ width: "18rem" }}>
  <Card.Img variant="top" src="holder.js/100px180" />
  <Card.Body>
    <Card.Title>Card Title</Card.Title>
    <Card.Text>
      Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of
      the card's content.
    </Card.Text>
    <Button variant="primary">Go somewhere</Button>
  </Card.Body>
</Card>
  );
};

export default App;
```

index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import { Card } from "react-bootstrap";
import { Button } from "react-bootstrap";

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));

export default Example;

// [enter image description here][1]
serviceWorker.unregister();
```

Comment: HI @Mikhail Nikiforov Can i ask where's the example coming from?

Answer (score 0):

If there is no error on your terminal, check your index.css. Most probably the global styling has blurred out the rendered elements.